# Where the problem can be in shortening an url in web address with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

So I'm trying to short the url from:

`trel/mycompany.php?company=f4f4f4`

to

`trel/f4f4f4`

with using the next htaccess rules, as in the example below. Finally I can access the page by typing `trel/f4f4f4`in the web address field but when I access it with the full link, it doesn't shorten.

I hope, I made the clear question, cause my native language in not English.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^mycompany.php
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ mycompany.php?company=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: _“but when I access it with the full link, it doesn't shorten”_ - well that’s because you have implemented _nothing_ yet that would achieve this … If you want this, then you need to explicitly write a rewriting statement for that case as well, right now you only have the other direction.

Comment: what kind of statement it should be?

Answer (score 0):

replace the last two lines with the below line in your .htaccess file

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^trel/([^/]*)$ /trel/mycompany.php?company=$1 [L]

Comment: unfortunately, the problem stays the same

Comment: is it psbl for you to show me the htaccess file codes ?

Comment: That is the full htaccess code I have. Or do you mean some other code?

Comment: replace the last two lines by RewriteRule ^trel/([^/]*)$ /trel/mycompany.php?company=$1 [L]